# Prove each of the sets is expressively complete if {f,->} is expressively complete where f is false in all its interpretations

Tags: logic

I am asked to suppose that $f$ is a sentence such that it is false in all its interpretations and that the set {$f,->$} is expressively complete. Using this I have to prove that:
{$-,->$} (which is a negation and conditional) is also expressively complete 
and that {$|$} (Or nand) is also expressively complete.

So I know the definition of expressive completeness means that any and all sentence can be represented with those elements in the set. Thus I have to prove that it suffices to use {$-,->$} to represent any sentence. With that being said I think i only have to show in this case that $f$ can be represented using {$-,->$}, is that correct?

What i did was i represented $f$ using the expression $-(A -> -A)$ or (denial of A conditional NOT A since this way this is always false just like $f$ is. Is this correct? Is it necessary to show a sentence in which both $f$ and $->$ are used and represented using {−,−>}?

Like $f->A = (-(A -> A) ->A)$

Similarily for {$|$} I showed since $(a|b) =-(a$&$b)$ and since $(a->b) = -(a$&$-b)$ then since $(-b=(b|b))$,

$(a->b) = -(a$&$(b|b)) = (a$|$(b|b))$ and so i have defined the conditional by nand.

Similarily, since $f = -(a->a) =-(a|(a|a))= ((a|(a|a))|(a|(a|a)))$ and so now f has been defined by nand.

Is this correct so far? Do i need to also define both $f$ and $->$ in one sentence by nand like so:

$f->A = (((a|(a|a))|(a|(a|a)))|(a|a))$

Thanks

Comment: Not very clear… If you have $\to$ and $\text f$ (usually named : $\bot$) what you have to do is to define $\lnot$ with them. This is very simple (and quite standard) : $\lnot A =_{def} A \to \text f$.

Comment: Youre right i did overcomplicate and it and ¬A=def A→f is far clearer. So is it enough to just define - with f and -> for this case? Similarily for | or nand ive noticed that (A|A)=def A->f as well since (A|A)=-(A&A) so whenever A Is true both sentences will be false and when A is false both will be true. So for this case i would just define | by saying, (A|A)=def A->f, right? Do i have to indivdually define | for each element of the set, like f and -> or is it enough to show its definition where both are being used?

Comment: (A|A)=def A->f  works if its the same Sentence letter but if it was (A|B) it doesnt work, how would i prove nand works using f and ->